# Print the length of the longest continuous sequence of alternating odd and even numbers

Tags: python, list, list-manipulation

How would I go about reading integers until -1 is input and then printing the length of the longest continuous sequence of numbers where there are 
alternating odd then even numbers?

I've achieved the first section but it went downhill from there.

Some testing lists:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,10,6,7,8,20,25,30,40,-1]              
[6,7,8,20,25,30,40,1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,-1]
```

Here is my code:

```
evenOdd=[]

while True:
    try:
        n=int(input())
        if n != -1:
            evenOdd.append(n)
    except:
            break
evenOdd=[]
longest = 0
length = 0
for i in range(len(evenOdd)):
    if ((evenOdd[i-2]% 2 == 0) and (evenOdd[i-1]% 2 == 1) and (evenOdd[i]% 2 == 0):
        length += 1
    else:
        longest = max(longest, length)
        length = 0

print(longest)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to keep track of the longest sequence as you go:

```
longest = []
current = []

while True:
    n = int(input("Enter value: "))
    if n == -1:
        break

    if current and current[-1] % 2 != n % 2:
        current.append(n)
    else:
        current = [n]

    if len(current) > len(longest):
        longest = current
```

The upside here is there's no post-processing to be done when the `-1` is entered, the result is ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.cycle` to alternate between a remainder of 0 and 1, and use `itertools.groupby` to group odd-even sequences:

```
from itertools import groupby, cycle
l = [1,2,3,4,5,10,6,7,8,20,25,30,40]
r = cycle((0, 1))
print(max(sum(1 for i in g) for _, g in groupby(l, key=lambda n: n % 2 == next(r))))
```

This outputs: `6` (since the longest odd-even sequence is `1,2,3,4,5,10`)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did. I think this might be simpler than the above examples.

def alternating(lst):

```
longSeries = []
currentSeries=[]
for i in range (len(lst)-1):
    if i == 0:
        currentSeries = [lst[0]]
    if(abs(lst[i] - lst[i+1]) % 2 ==  1):
        currentSeries.append(lst[i+1])
    else:
        currentSeries = [lst[i+1]]
    if(len(currentSeries) > len(longSeries)):
        longSeries = currentSeries


print ("The longest series is: " +str(longSeries))
print(len(longSeries))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can apply `itertools.groupby` twice:

```
import itertools
d = [[1,2,3,4,5,10,6,7,8,20,25,30,40,-1], [6,7,8,20,25,30,40,1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,-1]]
def key_func(d):
  start= not d[0]%2
  for i in d[1:]:
    if i%2 == start:
      start = (not i%2)
    else:
      return False
  return True

for l in d:
  new_l = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda x:x%2)]
  second_l = [[i for [i] in b] for a, b in itertools.groupby(new_l, key=lambda x:len(x) ==1) if a]
  print(max(second_l, key=lambda x:[key_func(x), len(x)]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, -1]
```